# Optimal value for Nginx worker_connections

Tags: nginx, connection, connection-pooling, worker, ngx-core-module

Nginx [`worker_connections`](http://nginx.org/r/worker_connections) *sets the maximum number of simultaneous connections that can be opened by a worker process. This number includes all connections (e.g. connections with proxied servers, among others), not only connections with clients. Another consideration is that the actual number of simultaneous connections cannot exceed the current limit on the maximum number of open files*. I have few queries around this:

1. What should be the optimal or recommended value for this?
2. What are the downsides of using a high number of worker connections?

Comment: plus one, good question!  post more!

Answer (score 2):

Setting lower limits may be useful when you may be resource-constrained.  Some connections, for example, keep-alive connections, are effectively wasting your resources (even if nginx is very efficient, which it is), and aren't required for correct operation of a general-purpose server.

Having a lower resource limit will indicate to nginx that you are low on physical resources, and those available should be allocated to new connections, rather than to serve the idling keep-alive connections.

What is the recommended value?  It's the default.

The defaults are all documented within the documentation:

> Default:  worker_connections 512;

And can be [confirmed in the source-code at `event/ngx_event.c`](http://ngx.su/src/event/ngx_event.c#DEFAULT_CONNECTIONS), too

> 13#define DEFAULT_CONNECTIONS  512

Comment: I understand that default is 512. But I am not sure why it should be the optimal value? It should be some correlation between a number of client concurrent connections and connections with the upstream connections.

Comment: @Aarti, but you didn't specify any of your requirements; you just asked what the optimal value is in and of itself!